# "Pimp my Library" in C++

Tags: c++, scala, polymorphism

In Scala, there's a design pattern often called "pimp my library". The basic idea is that we have some class `Foo` (presumably in some library that we can't modify), and we want `Foo` to act like it has some method or behavior `frobnicate`, we can use an implicit class to add the method after the fact.

```
implicit class Bar(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
  def frobnicate(): Unit = {
    // Something really cool happens here ...
  }
}
```

Then, if we have an instance of `Foo`, we can call `frobnicate` on it and, as long as `Bar` is in scope, the Scala compiler will be smart enough to implicitly cast `Foo` to `Bar`.

```
val foo = new Foo()
foo.frobnicate() // Correctly calls new Bar(foo).frobnicate()
```

I'd like to do this same sort of thing in C++. I know that C++ has implicit casts, but they don't seem to trigger when accessing members. For a concrete example, the following code in C++ produces an error.

```
class Foo {}; // Assume we can't modify this class Foo

class Bar {
private:
  Foo foo;
public:
  Bar(Foo foo) : foo(foo) {}
  void frobnicate() {
    cout << "Frobnicating :)" << endl;
  }
};

void frobnicate(Bar bar) {
  cout << "Frobnicating :)" << endl;
}

int main() {
  Foo value;
  frobnicate(value);  // This works
  value.frobnicate(); // But this doesn't
  return 0;
}
```

On the `value.frobnicate()` line, C++ doesn't seem to look for implicit conversions in that context.

> main.cc:30:9: error: ‘class Foo’ has no member named ‘frobnicate’

*Note: I'm compiling with C++11 right now. At a cursory glance at the newer C++ versions, it doesn't seem like anything that would affect this question has changed since then. C++11-compatible solutions are ideal, but a way to do this in newer C++ versions would be good as well, for didactic purposes.*

Comment: So what are you asking? How can we make `C++` accept Scala syntax? What problem are you trying to solve here? How to extend class functionality without extending the class?

Comment: This question seems like [an XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): You have a solution you want our help with, but doesn't tell us what the problem it is supposed to solve. Since you can't really do what you want there may be other solutions to your problem that you have missed.

Comment: C++ doesn't have extension-methods contrary to C#.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are describing is called **U**nified **F**unction **C**all **S**yntax (UFCS), and cannot be done in C++ as of today. Anyone who has worked with ranges and algorithm chaining in D can attest to how amazing that would be to have.

The lack of UFCS support is actually one of the main reason why the general modern wisdom is to use free-floating functions and ADL for anything that does not need to be virtual or encapsulation.

There has been proposals to bring D's UFCS to the language, but it's still just a proposal:

https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4165.pdf

**Edit:** For anyone wondering why we would ever want that feature, imagine being able to write the following:

```
std::vector<int> foo(const std::vector<int>& v) {
  return v.filter([](int x) {return x > 5;})
          .map([](int x) {return x*x;})
          .sort();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While you can't do exactly what you are asking you can inherit `Foo` and extend it.

```
class Bar : public Foo{
public:
void frobnicate() {
    cout << "Frobnicating :)" << endl;
  }
}
```

now `Bar` has everything `Foo` has plus the new method. see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Comment: I think OP wants to use `frobnicate` from a `Foo` instance instead of `Bar`. Basically, letting the compiler implicitly cast a `Foo` to a `Bar` to call the function.

Comment: FYI: http://www.cplusplus.com is not a very reliable source, consider using http://cppreference.com instead.

Comment: @Rakete1111 yep, that's why I said "While you can't do exactly what you are asking"
And the section I linked is good enough for what OP is asking, it's just the introductory tutorial

Answer (score 1):

> C++ doesn't seem to look for implicit conversions in that context.

That is correct.  The mechanism you're looking for doesn't exist in the language.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly, but...

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    void nothingUpMySleeve()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo!\n";
    }
};

class Bar
{
private:
    Foo & foo;

public:
    Bar(Foo & foo) : foo { foo }
    {
    }

    void frobnicate()
    {
        std::cout << "Frobnicating\n";
    }

    Foo * operator ->()
    {
        return &this->foo;
    }

    operator Foo &()
    {
        return this->foo;
    }
};

void thisFunctionOnlyAcceptsFoo(Foo & foo)
{
    std::cout << "Yes, that's a Foo\n";
}

void useExtendedType(Bar wrapper)
{
    // Use the extension function
    wrapper.frobnicate();

    // Use arrow notation to use the original functions
    wrapper->nothingUpMySleeve();

    // Implicit conversion kicks in when necessary
    thisFunctionOnlyAcceptsFoo(wrapper);
}

int main()
{
    Foo value;

    // Pass to a function that uses Bar
    useExtendedType(value);
}
```

I *really* don't recommend doing this in actual code though. It's just a cheap party trick.

It's not even clear whether `Bar` should own a copy of `Foo` or just reference it. I opted for just referencing because I'm presuming some other code is managing the lifetime of `Foo`, and this way `Bar` can be created and destroyed incredibly cheaply. You just have to be careful that `Bar`'s lifetime is always shorter than `Foo`'s, otherwise it's nasal demons I'm afraid.